# K framework install failure on MacOS catalina 10.15.6

Tags: installation, kframework

Hi I am on MacOS catalina 10.15.6 and am trying to install the K-framework using

```
brew reinstall kframework
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Fatal error:    OpamSystem.File_not_found("/usr/local/Cellar/kframework/5.0.0/lib/kframework/opamroot/repo/k/packages/mlgmp/mlgmp.20150824/opam")
```

I reinstalled ocaml and opam and that worked but the above error persists!

So I `brew uninstall kframework`  then `brew install kframework` but now get the error

```
   [ERROR] Compiler selection '4.10.0' is ambiguous. matching packages: { ocaml-base-compiler.4.10.0, ocaml-system.4.10.0 }
    The following dependencies couldn't be met:
      - mlgmp → ocaml < 4.06.0
          base of this switch (use `--unlock-base' to force)

No solution found, exiting
```

Any help much appreciated? david

Today it installs with no errors or warnings:

Trying to test/use kompile but all attempts to use lesson_1/imp1.k  fail with

```
dstr@Dstr lesson_1 % kompile imp.k
[Error] Compiler: Could not find sorts: [Id]
    Source(/Users/dstr/K/tutorial/1_k/4_imp++/lesson_1/./imp.k)
    Location(17,20,17,57)
dstr@Dstr lesson_1 % kompile --debug imp.k
org.kframework.utils.errorsystem.KEMException: [Error] Compiler: Could not find sorts: [Id]
    Source(/Users/dstr/K/tutorial/1_k/4_imp++/lesson_1/./imp.k)
    Location(17,20,17,57)
```

Is this because imp.k is out of date or is there something still wrong with my install?
(if imp.k is out of date where can I get some upto date _.k files?)

**No problems found the recent files all is working. Many thanks.**

Comment: Opam was supposed to be removed from the installation script for the kframework, but it looks like we messed up and may have introduced a bug. I think it's fixed now, but I'm not completely sure. Can you try `brew uninstall kframework; brew update; brew install kframework`

Comment: Thanks the install seems to work. But has warnings:  libffi is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

For compilers to find libffi you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libffi/include"

For pkg-config to find libffi you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig" . What file with uptodate ?.k can I use to test?